# How to detect GCC threading model with preprocessor?

Tags: g++, c-preprocessor, posix

I'm writing some library code, which can optionally make use of a certain C++11 feature (`thread_local` objects). However, I've [found a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/445/) that occurs only with the POSIX threading model (the Win32 one works fine) in MinGW-w64's builds of `g++`.

So, how can I detect, using the preprocessor, whether the current compiler is a `g++` with the POSIX threading model?

`g++ -v` yields `... Thread model: win32` or `... Thread model: posix` depending on the difference, but I need a way to conditionally compile code (to work around the bug) that doesn't involve invoking an extra instance of `g++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the macro __WINPTHREADS_VERSION is defined. If so, you are using posix threads on MinGW.

For example:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__WINPTHREADS_VERSION)
    Logic for MinGW win32 threads;
#else
    Logic for MinGW posix threads or Linux/UNIX;
#endif
```

Examples/References:

- http://savannah.gnu.org/support/?108150#comment0
- https://projects.kde.org/projects/kdesupport/emerge/repository/revisions/master/entry/portage/win32libs/libssh/0002-add-a-way-to-test-ssh-connections-on-windows.patch#L114

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Note that you need to include `<thread>` for this to be defined (and even though `std::thread` doesn't work in the Win32 threading model, the header still exists, thus allowing portable threading model detection).